# How can I call a non static function from another class from a broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have a function with an increment counter and I call it when the user click a button.
I want to make a new button when user press it call this function every second.
I used alarm manager and works fine.But when I try to call this function from broadcast receiver give me error because is not static.What can i do?

```
public class MyStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  Toast.makeText(context, "Send ....",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  //Intent service = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
      //context.startService(service);    
      //String msg = intent.getStringExtra("data");

  //String msg="data";

  a1class.function1();

}

public void function1(){

  counter++;
  //Toast.MakeText( counter );

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Either make `function1()` `static` or, assuming `a1class` is the class its in, create an instance of the class and call the function that way

```
a1class a1class = new a1class();
a1class.function1();
```

Comment: I can not convert my function to static...i have increment counter...Any tutorial for this?

Comment: Then access it by instantiating an instance of the class as I have shown in the example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a non static method you need a instance of the class to call it on.

You can make a static method that returns the instance like this

```
private static ClassName instance;

public static ClassName getInstance(){
   if (instance == null){
      instance = new ClassName();
   }
   return instance;
}
```

You can also set the instance in the onCreate method.